# Trouble Loading CSS in IE from Linux server

Tags: java, css, spring

i am facing issues in CSS getting loaded in IE-11 when application is deployed on a tomcat server in LINUX env. in windows, in eclipse it is working fine.
Application works in expected way in FF in all scenarios.
my css, JS, all folders are directly created in webapp directory. I am using Spring mvc with JSP. 
this is how the path is given in jsp. i have checked, the names of all folders are correct. 
actual path on jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/gvgrid.js"></script>
```

i have tried to replace the path as

```
src="/scripts/gvgrid.js"
```

but it doesn't work. I am also using tiles in the application.
does anybody has any pointers to this issue. it would be really helpful. thanks

Comment: When you using IE-11, press Ctrl + U to see HTML source, then try press at link to `gvgrid.js` file. Then, let's me know your result!

Comment: I see the following in source                                                                     <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/gvgrid.js"></script>